# Visual Studio: can't load the Windows forms designer, but the project builds and works correctly

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to edit the GUI of a windows-forms application that is currently working correctly.
(I didn't personally make this application).
I can't edit the code, since there are these comments:

```
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
```

But I can't open the design either since it shows this error:
"Could not load file or assembly 'xxx', Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Where 'xxx' is the name of a dll in the same solution.

DETAILS:
In this solution there are a lot of other dll projects, some are C++, others C++/CLI and some C#.
The application builds and works properly, the only problem is with loading the designers.
The dependencies seem to be referenced correctly, in fact, the dll marked as missing is present in the output directory of the windows-forms project.
Configuration: Debug, x64

I've already tried cleaning, rebuilding, restarting VS and other basic troubleshooting methods.

Comment: You can edit the code. It's generally not needed so should be avoided unless required and, if you do it, you need to be very careful that all you do makes sense and doesn't break anything. If you are going to do it, be sure to have a backup first, which you should already because you should be using source control. That said, I doubt you need it in this case.

Comment: Does your project reference those other projects or does it reference the compiled libraries directly? If the latter, do those compiled libraries actually exist where the references expect them to be? Can you build those other projects individually, rather than building the whole solution?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks, at least I have a workaround now

Comment: @jmcilhinney it references the projects

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? In addition, for unmanaged C++ you should use pinvoke.